# Windows 8 Metro App only starts in debugger if file is read

Tags: c#, windows-8, xna, async-await

i'm writing a Windows 8 Metro App with XNA and Monogame.
I'm using this code for file reading:

> File reading:

```
private void getDoc(String filename)
    {
        readstate = 0;

        try
        {
            // get the file
            //StorageFile myStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);
            String path = @"birdy2 - win8\XML\XMLFiles\" + filename + ".xml";
            StorageFile myStorageFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(path);


            var readThis = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(myStorageFile);
            String txt = "";
            foreach (var line in readThis)
            {
                txt += line.ToString();
            }
            if (txt.Length > 0)
            {
                doc = XDocument.Parse(txt);
            }
            readstate = 1;

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            doc = null;
            readstate = 2;
        }

    }
```

And i call the method with:

```
        XDocument gameinfo = null;
        try
        {
            getDoc("gameinfo.xml");
            while (readstate == 0) { }
            gameinfo = doc;
        }
        catch { gameinfo = null; }
```

The Problem:
If i debug the App, everything is working fine.
If i release the App and after that i start it direct from the Win8 start screen, the App does not start.
I found out that

```
while (readstate == 0) { }
```

readstate never gets any different than 0 in release state. But don't know why.

I'm happy over every answer.
Thank you!

---

---

Thank you for the fast answer Nahel!
I rewrote the code, but still it doesn't work for me, same behaviour as before.

```
private async Task<int> getDoc(String filename)
    {
        try
        {
            // get the file
            StorageFile myStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(filename);                         
            var readThis = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(myStorageFile);

            String txt = "";
            foreach (var line in readThis)
            {
                txt += line.ToString();
            }
            if (txt.Length > 0)
            {
                doc = XDocument.Parse(txt);
            }
            return 1;

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            doc = null;
            return 2;
        }

    }
```

And for loading:

```
        XDocument gameinfo = null;
        try
        {
            Task<int> tsk = getDoc("gameinfo.xml");               
            int result = tsk.Result;
            if (result == 1)
            {
                gameinfo = doc;
            }
            else
            {
                gameinfo = null;
            }

        }
        catch { gameinfo = null; }
```

Comment: Updated my answer according your new code segment.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a method that has some `async` operations without marking it as `async`.

Mark the `getDoc` method as `async` and await it where you call it.

Instead of using the readstate variable, return an `int` from the `getDoc` method and use that object on your main call. Or even better, return the document you want to use.

Here is a picture of how an async/await call functions:

[image]

If you have an await inside your method, once the code gets to it; it will return to its caller. Having an infinite loop after that is not helping you.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

**Update:**

According to your new answer, you are missing the `await` on the `getDoc` call.

Replace:

```
Task<int> tsk = getDoc("gameinfo.xml");
```

with:

```
Task<int> tsk = await getDoc("gameinfo.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

it was not possible to use:

```
Task<int> tsk = await getDoc("gameinfo.xml");
```

what worked for me, was using the first solution i presented and to change:

```
while (readstate == 0) { }
```

to

```
   while (readstate == 0) {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Yield();        
    }
```